# Handling queries in pandas when a CSV input contains multiple duplicate columns?

Tags: pandas

I have a fairly simple CSV that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

When I use pandas to read the CSV, columns that have the same name automatically gets renamed with a ".n" notation, as follows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> food = pd.read_csv("food.csv")
>>> food
    Order Number Item Description  Item Cost Item Description.1  Item Cost.1 Item Description.2  Item Cost.2
0            110        Chow Mein       5.00                NaN          NaN                NaN          NaN
1            111             Cake       1.50          Chocolate        13.10             Noodle         3.75
2            112        Chocolate      11.00              Chips         5.75                NaN          NaN
3            113         Sandwich       6.25               Milk         2.00                Ice         0.50
4            114        Chocolate      13.10              Water         0.25                NaN          NaN
5            115              Tea       1.00          Milkshake         2.80          Chocolate        13.10
6            116        Green Tea       1.25                NaN          NaN                NaN          NaN
7            117           Burger       2.00              Fries         3.50                NaN          NaN
8            118        Chocolate       5.00          Green Tea         1.50                NaN          NaN
9            119            Tonic       3.00             Burger         3.75               Milk         2.00
10           120           Orange       1.50          Milkshake         4.20                NaN          NaN
>>>
```

food.csv:

```
Order Number,Item Description,Item Cost,Item Description,Item Cost,Item Description,Item Cost
110,Chow Mein,5,,,,
111,Cake,1.5,Chocolate,13.1,Noodle,3.75
112,Chocolate,11,Chips,5.75,,
113,Sandwich,6.25,Milk,2,Ice,0.5
114,Chocolate,13.1,Water,0.25,,
115,Tea,1,Milkshake,2.8,Chocolate,13.1
116,Green Tea,1.25,,,,
117,Burger,2,Fries,3.5,,
118,Chocolate,5,Green Tea,1.5,,
119,Tonic,3,Burger,3.75,Milk,2
120,Orange,1.5,Milkshake,4.2,,
```

As such, queries that rely on the column names will only work if they match the first column (e.g.):

```
>>> print(food[(food['Item Description'] == "Chocolate") & (food['Item Cost'] == 13.10)]['Order Number'].to_string(index=False))
114
```

While I can technically lengthen the masks to include the .1 and .2 columns, this seems relatively inefficient, especially when the number of duplicated columns is large (in this example there are only 3 sets of duplicated columns, but in other datasets, I have a large number which would not work well if I just construct a mask for each column.)

I am not sure if I am approaching this the right way or if I am missing something simple (like in loading the CSV) or if there are some groupbys I can do that can answer the same question (i.e. Find the order numbers when the order contains an item that has chocolate listed that costs $13.10).

Would the problem be different if it's something like: average all the costs of chocolates paid for all the orders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often easier to operate on a table in "long" form instead of "wide" form that you currently have.

There's example code below to convert from an example wide_df:

[image]

To a long df version:

[image]

In the long_df version each row is a unique Order/Item and now we don't have to store any null values. Pandas also makes it easy to perform grouping operations on tables in long form. Here's what the `agg` table looks like from the code below

[image]

You can also easily make your query of finding orders where a chocolate cost $13.10 by `long_df[long_df['Description'].eq('Chocolate') & long_df['Cost'].eq(13.10)]['Order Number'].unique()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order Number': ['Order_01', 'Order_02', 'Order_03', 'Order_04', 'Order_05', 'Order_06', 'Order_07', 'Order_08', 'Order_09', 'Order_10'], 
    'Item Description': ['Burger', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Tonic', 'Green Tea', 'Sandwich', 'Orange', 'Burger', 'Cake', 'Chow Mein'], 
    'Item Cost': [7, 10, 4, 1, 10, 7, 9, 9, 6, 3], 
    'Item Description.1': ['Tonic', 'Burger', 'Green Tea', 'Sandwich', 'Orange', None, 'Chocolate', None, 'Chocolate', 'Tea'],
    'Item Cost.1': [4.0, 1.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, np.nan, 6.0, np.nan, 8.0, 3.0], 
    'Item Description.2': [None, 'Chow Mein', 'Chow Mein', 'Chocolate', 'Tea', None, 'Burger', None, 'Tea', 'Green Tea'], 
    'Item Cost.2': [np.nan, 8.0, 1.0, 9.0, 9.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, 1.0, 9.0],
    'Item Description.3': [None, 'Sandwich', 'Orange', 'Cake', 'Tonic', None, None, None, 'Sandwich', 'Burger'],
    'Item Cost.3': [np.nan, 5.0, 9.0, 2.0, 7.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 4.0], 
    'Item Description.4': [None, 'Green Tea', 'Burger', 'Green Tea', 'Cake', None, None, None, None, 'Orange'],
    'Item Cost.4': [np.nan, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 10.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0], 
    'Item Description.5': [None, None, 'Tea', 'Burger', 'Chocolate', None, None, None, None, 'Sandwich'], 
    'Item Cost.5': [np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 5.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4.0], 
    'Item Description.6': [None, None, 'Tonic', 'Tea', 'Burger', None, None, None, None, 'Chocolate'], 
    'Item Cost.6': [np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 2.0, 8.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 9.0],
})

# Convert table to long form
desc_cols = [c for c in df.columns if 'Desc' in c]
cost_cols = [c for c in df.columns if 'Cost' in c]

desc_df = df.melt(id_vars='Order Number', value_vars=desc_cols, value_name='Description')
cost_df = df.melt(id_vars='Order Number', value_vars=cost_cols, value_name='Cost')

long_df = pd.concat((desc_df[['Order Number','Description']], cost_df[['Cost']]), axis=1).dropna()
long_df.insert(1,'Item Number',long_df.groupby('Order Number').cumcount().add(1))
long_df = long_df.sort_values(['Order Number','Item Number'])

# Calculate group info
group_info = long_df.groupby('Order Number').agg(
    ordered_chocolate = ('Description', lambda d: d.eq('Chocolate').any()),
    total_cost = ('Cost','sum'),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of a simpler approach with pandas' wide_to_long function
(i will use the df provided by @mitoRibo in another answer)

documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order Number': ['Order_01', 'Order_02', 'Order_03', 'Order_04', 'Order_05', 'Order_06', 'Order_07', 'Order_08', 'Order_09', 'Order_10'],
    'Item Description': ['Burger', 'Cake', 'Cake', 'Tonic', 'Green Tea', 'Sandwich', 'Orange', 'Burger', 'Cake', 'Chow Mein'],
    'Item Cost': [7, 10,     4, 1, 10, 7, 9, 9, 6, 3],
    'Item Description.1': ['Tonic', 'Burger', 'Green Tea', 'Sandwich', 'Orange', None, 'Chocolate', None, 'Chocolate', 'Tea'],
    'Item Cost.1': [4.0, 1.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, np.nan, 6.0, np.nan, 8.0, 3.0],
    'Item Description.2': [None, 'Chow Mein', 'Chow Mein', 'Chocolate', 'Tea', None, 'Burger', None, 'Tea', 'Green Tea'],
    'Item Cost.2': [np.nan, 8.0, 1.0, 9.0, 9.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, 1.0, 9.0],
    'Item Description.3': [None, 'Sandwich', 'Orange', 'Cake', 'Tonic', None, None, None, 'Sandwich', 'Burger'],
    'Item Cost.3': [np.nan, 5.0, 9.0, 2.0, 7.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 4.0],
    'Item Description.4': [None, 'Green Tea', 'Burger', 'Green Tea', 'Cake', None, None, None, None, 'Orange'],
    'Item Cost.4': [np.nan, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 10.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0],
    'Item Description.5': [None, None, 'Tea', 'Burger', 'Chocolate', None, None, None, None, 'Sandwich'],
    'Item Cost.5': [np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 5.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4.0],
    'Item Description.6': [None, None, 'Tonic', 'Tea', 'Burger', None, None, None, None, 'Chocolate'],
    'Item Cost.6': [np.nan, np.nan, 8.0, 2.0, 8.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 9.0],
})

df.rename(columns={'Item Description': 'Item Description.0', 'Item Cost': 'Item Cost.0'}, inplace=True)
  
long = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Item Description', 'Item Cost'], i="Order Number", j="num_after_col_name", sep='.')
```